# the trait `LoadConnection` is not implemented for `deadpool::managed::Object<Manager<SqliteConnection>>`

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-diesel, rust-axum

#### Context

I'm currently trying to implement `deadpool_diesel` and `diesel` to my api made with Axum but I'm getting an error that I'm not sure to understand.

My guess is that I'm maybe doing something wrong with the usage of `State` but I'm still discovering Axum and Diesel so I don't really know for sure

#### Error

```
the trait `LoadConnection` is not implemented for `deadpool::managed::Object<Manager<SqliteConnection>>`
```

#### Code

```rust
// user.rs

pub async fn get_all_users(State(pool): State<Pool>) {
    let mut conn = pool.get().await.unwrap();

    let all_users = users
    .select(UserInformation::as_select())
    .load::<UserInformation>(&mut conn) // <---------- The error is appearing on the &mut conn
    .unwrap();
}
```

```rust
// main.rs

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let pool_manager = Manager::new(Config::get_db_path(), Runtime::Tokio1);
    let pool = Pool::builder(pool_manager)
        .max_size(50)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(hello))
        .route("/user", Router::new())
        .with_state(pool);

    let addr = format!("0.0.0.0:{}", config.port);

    axum::Server::bind(&addr.parse().unwrap())
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diesel`is not async and therefore `deadpool-diesel` added a sync wrapper around it. You need to call interact on the object passing it a closure like in the example code:

```rust
let result = conn.interact(|conn| {
    let query = select("Hello world!".into_sql::<Text>());
    query.get_result::<String>(conn)
}).await?;
```

So my code should look like that:

```rust
pub async fn get_all_users(State(pool): State<Pool>) {
    let mut conn = pool.get().await.unwrap();
   
    let all_users = conn.interact(|conn| users
        .select(UserInformation::as_select())
        .load::<UserInformation>(&mut conn)
        .unwrap()
    ).await.unwrap();
}
```

Original answer by `deadpool` owner: https://github.com/bikeshedder/deadpool/issues/267#issuecomment-1647989137